# Error while geting Firebase Phone Auth OTP

Tags: java, android, firebase, flutter, authentication

I am trying to implement Firebase Phone Verification. I have enabled phone verification on firebase console. I have generated keystore and added the SHA signatures to the console.

dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    def multidex_version = "2.0.1"
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.0.0')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:$multidex_version"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.google.guava:listenablefuture:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava'

}
```

phone_verification.dart

```
                await FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(
                  phoneNumber: '+1234567890',

                  verificationCompleted: (PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
                    print('verificationCompleted');
                    
                  },
                  verificationFailed: (FirebaseAuthException e) {
                    print('verificationFailed');
                    if (e.code == 'invalid-phone-number') {
                      print('The provided phone number is not valid.');
                    }
                    else {
                      print('Some error occoured: $e');
                    }
                  },
                  codeSent: (String verificationId, int resendToken) async {
                    print('codeSent');

                    // Update the UI - wait for the user to enter the SMS code
                    String smsCode = '123456';

                    // Create a PhoneAuthCredential with the code
                    PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential = PhoneAuthProvider.credential(verificationId: verificationId, smsCode: smsCode);
                  
                  },
                  timeout: const Duration(seconds: 60),
                  codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationId) {
                    print("Timeout: $verificationId");
                  },
                );
```

When the above block is executed following error is received.
Console Output:

```
E/FirebaseAuth: [GetAuthDomainTask] Error getting project config. Failed with {
      "error": {
        "code": 400,
        "message": "INVALID_CERT_HASH",
        "errors": [
          {
            "message": "INVALID_CERT_HASH",
            "domain": "global",
            "reason": "invalid"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
     400
V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 1165
E/zza: Failed to get reCAPTCHA token - calling backend without app verification
```

Comment: Along with Error log please add more detail on what you are trying to do. Add the code snippet from where you getting this error

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Any idea?

Comment: Facing the same issue..

Comment: Same issue. Seems to be related to the app Gradle firebase auth library. Updating it didn't work for me though.

Comment: did you add the sha1 to the firebase console?

Comment: I have added both SHA-1 and SHA-256 to the console @UrielFrankel

Comment: Hey! Did you find any working solution?

Answer (score 14):

This problem related to SHA1 and SHA256 keys. You have to add them to authenticate your certs.

Goto

- Firebase Console of your project
- Authentication
- Project Setting (From Setting button near Project Overview)
- Add fingerprint
- Add SHA-1 and SHA-256 values of your keystore.

You can get keystores from gradle like this.

> ./gradlew signingReport

Read this for more information: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth#enable-app-verification

Answer (score 5):

Error 400 means bad request, it  can be due to any of the following three reasons:-

1. Check if phone authentication option is enabled in firebase console or not. Enable it.
2. Check if Android Device Check API is enabled in [Google cloud console](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/androidcheck.googleapis.com) or not. Enable it.
3. Check if SHA-1 and SHA-256 are added to your firebase project or not. Add it as follows:

Open your project in firebase console -> Go to project setting -> Click on add fingerprint (at the bottom of the page) -> Add the SHA-1 and SHA-256 values there.

[image: Image for reference]

You can get the SHA values of your android studio project as follows:-

Click on gradle on top right side -> task -> android -> signingReport -> Get the SHA values at the bottom after running signingReort
[image: Image for reference]

Follow the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth#enable-app-verification) if issue in not resolved.

Answer (score 3):

Enable **Phone** option in the Firebase Console under **Authentication**

Answer (score 0):

I have been stuck here for a week only to find a key I was using was restricted to another app and was therefore failing when trying to use it in my app. So I first removed the restriction in the credentials tab in Android device verification and everything went back to normal

Answer (score 0):

We need to add one extra step to @Anat Bharti Answer: [Enable GCS Device Verification API on Your Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fK5Ba.jpg)

Enable GCS Device Verification API on Your Project.
That solves Everything, You not even asked to Verify capcha on your Physical device.